# When will a string have a repeating substring?

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words

What's the minimum number M such that any string with M elements taking values from 1 to N will have a substring repeating itself at least 2 times in a row? The case where N=2 is trivial, you have M=4: 1212 for example the substring 12 repeats itself 2 times in a row, or 1111 where the substring 1 reapeats itself 4 times in a row. It's difficult to find the number even for N=3...

Comment: The question is if there's a number of elements such that any string with this number of elements will have a substring repeating itself 2 times in a row

Comment: You already showed that $4$ works.  I think, I'm really not clear on what the question is.  These are binary strings?  You say "string where values from $1$ to $N$" .  Anyway, if it's binary then you have to have a repeat within any four consecutive entries.

Comment: i think i made the question more clear, sorry for the mess

Comment: Oh.  There is no length $M$ that works, even for $N=3$.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_word

Comment: I think that is $$M=N+1$$

Comment: @lulu: If you don't mind, you could flesh that out to an answer. I do realize that you may not want to reproduce relevant bits of a wikipedia page :-). Your call, of course. Also, the question may get closed before you get a chance :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  Done.  Well, I described the standard construction, due to Thue,  and included links to the relevant proofs.  The Stanford notes, linked to at the bottom of my post, are very thorough.

Answer (score 4):

As requested in the comments...

Words of the desired type are said to be "square free". As the OP correctly observes, for binary strings there aren't many instances.  $0,1,01,10,101,010$ are the only examples.  Somewhat surprisingly, however, even for ternary strings there are infinitely long examples.  Wikipedia has a good survey [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_word)

Perhaps the simplest, and so far as I know the first, example of an infinite square free ternary word was produced by Thue.  It begins with the so-called Thue-Morse binary string, obtained by starting with either character and then successively appending the complement of what's come before.  Thus:

$$1,\;10,\;1001,\;10010110,\;1001011001101001,\dots$$

Thue's square free example is then derived from this by taking successive differences. Thus:

$$-1,0,1,-1,1,0,-1,\dots$$

References for these and related results can be found in the Wikipedia article linked to earlier.  The proof that the difference sequence of the Thue-Morse word is square free is somewhat lengthy, but it isn't difficult. A good reference for that can be found [here](https://sumo.stanford.edu/pdfs/smt2014/thuemorse-solutions.pdf).